# Stored Procedures instead of SELECT / INSERT / UPDATE?

Tags: mysql, performance, stored-procedures

I'm already using Triggers heavily to avoid unnecessary PHP code, but didnt actually use many Stored procedures yet.

I was asking myself, if it actually would make sense to move all SELECT / INSERT / UPDATE's in Stored Procedures, and not have actual SQL (besides Transactions, and such stuff) but only Procedures.

Would that actually make sense? What drawbacks would I face?

By reading the MySQL Doc, I found this:

> "Stored routines can provide improved performance because less
>   information needs to be sent between the server and the client. **The
>   tradeoff is that this does increase the load on the database server
>   because more of the work is done on the server side and less is done
>   on the client (application) side. Consider this if many client
>   machines (such as Web servers) are serviced by only one or a few
>   database servers.** "

Well, if I would use the Stored Procedures mainly as wrappers around SQL Code that I would execute anyway, would that really make much of a difference for the Database Server?

Mainly, I would like to know if this actually is a good idea, and what drawbacks I may face doing that.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Surely if you're using triggers instead of client-side code then almost all the work is already being done in the database? By moving it to a single stored procedure you remove a layer of obfuscation and can use only stored procedures.

Comment: In applications where one wishes to limit and audit user behaviour, I've granted users permission only to execute stored procedures and then performed the desired work (including audit logging) from within there.  That way, I know that a malicious user cannot perform any database action except those that have been predefined.